# Ruby on Rails-Action mailer no as per desired?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

i have 2 models `po` and `send`

**po: has_many sends**

**send: belongs_to po**

`send`

[image: send table]

`po`

[image: po table]

`send_controller`

```
class SendsController < ApplicationController
 def new
 @send = Send.new
 end

def create
  @send = Send.new(params[:send])
if @send.save
     Pomailer.registration_confirmation(@send).deliver
    flash[:success] = "Send mail"
    redirect_to capax_path
else
    flash[:warning] = "mail not send"
    redirect_to capax_path
  end
end
```

`pomailer`

```
class Pomailer < ActionMailer::Base
   default from: "from@example.com"

  def registration_confirmation(po)
     @po = po

  mail(:to => "xyz@yahoo.co.in", :subject => " New purchase order send by " )


    end

   end
```

**Expected outcome to be mail**

[image]

**How can i send the details of the po into the mailer from send controller ?**

Comment: how far have you reached with this ,, where are u stuck actually?

Comment: how to get the details of po into the mail..i can easily do in console `@send  = Send.find(3).po` i get all po record, but what in mail?

Comment: @send.po will give the associated po. am i right ?

Comment: ok i am adding sample code ,, u can refer it and alter , i cannot exactly add solution because i dont have application working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNTESTED CODE:  use it as a reference.

```
class SendsController < ApplicationController

def create
 @send = Send.new(params[:send])
 if @send.save
   Pomailer.registration_confirmation(@send.po).deliver
   flash[:success] = "Send mail"
   redirect_to capax_path
 else
   flash[:warning] = "mail not send"
   redirect_to capax_path
 end
end
```

pomailer:

```
class Pomailer < ActionMailer::Base
 default from: "from@example.com"
 def registration_confirmation(po)
 @po = po
 mail(:to => "xyz@yahoo.co.in", :subject => " New purchase order send by " )
end
```

end

In views create a Pomailer folder and add a file registration_confirmation.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Dear <%= @po.vname %></h1>,
   <p>
   You have purchase order with invoice no <%= @po.invoiceno %>.
   </p>
  <p> 
  ......
   add your required information using @po object.
  .....
  </p>
  <p>Thanks !</p>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE:
This is a sample code ,, i cannot give u exact working code without going throught application,,But i am sure this will help you to go farther.