# Form Data to HTML Email

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application with a form for job applicants.  Right now, when a user fills out the form the data is sent to an email in this format:

```
Position_Applied_For: 
Name: 
Telephone_Number: 
Alt_Telephone_Number: 
Physical_Address: 
How_Long_At_Address: 
Desired_Salary_Or_Hourly_Rate: 
Specified_Hours: 
Date_Can_Start_Work: 
etc..
```

I'm trying to have the output sent to look like an actual job application using html to make the document and have the parameters fill the fields in the document.  What would be the best solution to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: you can design HTML template using css.are you in search of some plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you asking for exactly.. refer this link [action mailer design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180632/ruby-on-rails-action-mailer-no-as-per-desired/23180814#23180814). 
You can edit mailer template in views and design its style using css, to look like job application.